# Delay in receiving emails sent from SendGrid (app is on Windows Azure, mvc.net)

Tags: email, azure, sendgrid

I send an email through send grid using SendGridMessage.DeliverAsync. It takes about 20 minutes for the email to arrive. I am pasting below the header information of the email as received by the recipient. All company information has been replaced by fictional data:

```
Return-path: <bounces+1776648-b90d-rec=example.com@sendgrid.me>
Envelope-to: rec@example.com
Delivery-date: Wed, 27 May 2015 15:48:53 -0400
Received: from o1.f.az.sendgrid.net ([208.117.55.132]:22426)
    by server37.web-hosting.com with esmtps (UNKNOWN:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128)
    (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <bounces+1776648-b90d-rec=example.com@sendgrid.me>)
    id 1YxhJt-003sMA-8G
    for rec@example.com; Wed, 27 May 2015 15:48:53 -0400
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=sendgrid.me; 
    h=content-type:mime-version:from:to:subject; s=smtpapi; 
    bh=e8YGVEGwW8wzxqhpuiTstqZPRIs=; b=MLyTlQTi5Y4eOlmcNk65t0Fqv+8cp
    WoAtekeb+ld1HBI1kk4CQ1ycmJ7LP6r/ZJKI0+0+fwy0hsO5F7ywT7twv6t9Z/M2
    BYxCuE5heMWP5tjyIkfJYjIDf8fT3OM43bq30+NC69GQWJFr+CHn2ms/OgmSahvD
    PhQ71p1yBFagxY=
Received: by filter-403.sjc1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter-403.17268.55661A831A
        2015-05-27 19:27:00.592426035 +0000 UTC
Received: from MTc3NjY0OA (unknown [23.97.229.110])
    by ismtpd-004 (SG) with HTTP id 14d96d793b7.30c5.15e6fe
    Wed, 27 May 2015 19:27:00 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="===============1502686111627047378=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Example Support <admin@example.com>
To: Rec Martel <rec@example.com>
Subject: Thank you for Signing up with Example!
Message-ID: <14d96d793b7.30c5.15e6fe@ismtpd-004>
Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 19:27:12 +0000 (UTC)
X-SG-EID: IASZyfUggCe5SBfFgEPkfXBDb6ZCY09R57ALGWkRenTMTMZdvb6XDq63Z6REVqqqqh1THbQI2y+Su7
 fi7CkNm41AX9xYJayZj7L4Nq9kdKIQjkQVy89oVT4OWeRVj/QSAmE5TEgSMY+XRBmQ/JygwCuz1U6r
 eB7+RE6w3Aht84U=
X-From-Rewrite: unmodified, no actual sender determined from check mail permissions
```

Can anyone tell me why the delay is happening and how can I fix it?

Regards,
Zawar

Answer (score 2):

If you experienced this within the last hour (as per your question timestamp) it is likely because Sendgrid is currently experiencing a [serious outage](https://twitter.com/sendgrid_ops/status/603667201208426496) which is causing ~60 min. email delays in some cases.